# Time Series Book Recommendation

Tags: time-series

Can i asked for a text book recommendation to study time series analysis if i don't have a strong background in Probability? My background is in Pure Mathematics and my probability background is only as good as the basic understanding of discrete and continuous random variables. I tried many text but all of them requires a strong probability background.

Comment: The indicated duplicate seems sufficiently close in that the answers would also be answers to your question. You would get at least basic coverage of some of the 'standard' time series stuff and be in a position to perhaps identify if you need more probability so as to tackle more sophisticated texts. To properly understand the material, you may want more probability than you have (even if it's not as formal or deep as you need for some of the more mathematical texts). There are some reasonable basic probability texts around that might suffice for the first few steps along this path.